# Get control's values from another page

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

**Windows 8 Application C#**

I have several TextBox and ComboBox controls on a page. On another page I would like to get the values of these controls to use them again (e.g cboTeam.SelectedValue).

Is there a proper way to get these values in the other page?

EDIT:

XAML Code:

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Test}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding test}"
          x:Name="cboTeam1"
          Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"
          Margin="0,13,0,12"/>
```

Get the ItemsSource:

```
cboTeam1.ItemsSource = ItemRepository.getJPLItems();
```

In my repository:

```
public static List<TeamItem> getJPLItems()
{
    if (JPLItems.Count == 0)
    {
        JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Anderlecht", Image = "Jpl/Anderlecht.png", ItemType = ItemType.JupilerProLeague });
        JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Beerschot", Image = "Jpl/Beerschot.png", ItemType = ItemType.JupilerProLeague });
        JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Cercle Brugge", Image = "Jpl/Cercle Brugge.png", ItemType = ItemType.JupilerProLeague });
    }
}
```

So my `cboTeam1` is filled with: "Anderlecht", "Beerschot", "Cercle Brugge".

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific? What do these contain? Where do they come from? (I.e sql database, datatable, user input) etc. But you need to reference these also so that you can call them. My advice is research this more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem:

When navigating to the other page I passed the value:

```
  var selected = cboTeam1.SelectedValue as TeamItem;
  getInfo gI = new SportsBetting.Scoreandinvite.getInfo() { Team1 = selected.Description};

  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Scoreandinvite), gI);
```

On the other page i've created a class:

```
    public class getInfo
    {
        public string Team1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

In the OnNavigatedTo method:

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        getInfo gI = (getInfo)e.Parameter;
        Team1.Text = gI.Team1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Combobox` has `SelectedIndex` property. Through this property, you can get selected value in another page. I use this in my MVVM. Just bind this property to some public property in my `ViewModel` and then i can use it elsewhere. Moreover this binding could be two way.

Comment: ComboBox cboTeam1 is on the first page, TextBlock Team1 on the second page. Team1 needs to get the value of the selected item in cboTeam1.

Tried this: <TextBlock x:Name="Team1" Text="{Binding ElementName=cboTeam1, Path=SelectedIndex}"></TextBlock> but no result.

Comment: You need to have same `DataContext` for both pages. I use third class where I store these properties. This third class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Now you can bind to some `int` property in this third class to both `ComboBox` and `TextBlock`.